# Bootstrap force button group icon to stay on same line (grid system)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap button groups as shown [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-split).

However, due to being inside a `col-md-1`, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQUxF.png) happens. How can I avoid the carat flowing onto a new line? I mean, it overlapping with the one beside it wont be pretty, but it'd be a darn site prettier than the carat icon falling onto the next line.

Code:

```
<div class="col-md-1" >
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" >
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">01-01-2002</a>
        <button type="button" style="padding: 2px;" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="caret"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just wrap for the line. use nowrap

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: "just wrap for the line"? What do you mean? I tried adding white-space: nowrap onto the col-md-1 element, but nothing changed.

Comment: why col-md-1? u need a button!

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. Have a look at my code, where in that code would you write `style='white-space: nowrap'`?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at my image and facepalming, i removed the padding (green area on picture), which stopped the button from wrapping before the two buttons touched each other. That worked enough for me.